Securing IoT Devices with granularity at attribute level
In NGSI-LD, I am using IoTAgent JSON for the integration of a multitude of devices in an Orion-LD Context Broker.
I have a question about the possibilities offered natively by FIWARE for securing IoT devices. According to the documentation, security mechanisms can be applied to control access to IoT Devices:

For devices using HTTP: using PEP proxy and PDP to control requests to endpoints.
For devices using MQTT: using the security mechanisms provided by the MQTT protocol.

I wanted to know if it is possible to apply authorisation at attribute level. That is, to be able to control access control policies for certain attributes provided by IoT Devices.
The idea is, having a set of devices publishing measurements, to control access to these at attribute level. In this way, the client that consumes these measurements coming from the IoT Devices will only have access to the attributes that the owner of the devices has decided.

You can integrate the AuthzForce on your architecture. It can be used along side with the Wilma PEP proxy to have a attribute level access control. The access control can be set by XACML (eXtensible Access Control Markup Language).
You can try it by running the FIWARE tutorial: https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.XACML-Access-Rules
With the XACML you can set rules to check ie the header NGSILD-Tenant to be equals as FIWARE-IOT, or the entity id to start with a specific URN urn:ngsi-ld:XXXXX:XXXX
